# Android: Usar Java 8 en el proyecto-gradle

Tags: android, gradle, java-8

Estoy empezando un pequeño proyecto en Android y me he encontrado que por defecto las grandes features de Java 8 no estan disponibles: Lambdas, streams, Time API y otras que no me dado

Este es mi build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.wesosdqueso.reportesseguridad"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

No estoy seguro que me falte modificar, pero no puedo usar LocalDate. Las lambdas si funcionan. Y no, no quiere volver a la pesadilla de la clase Date.

**EDIT:**

Ya encontré la solución, solo tenía que cambiar el API level a 26. Cierren esta pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres habilitar Java 8 para usar lambdas (et al) realiza lo siguiente:

Si deseas habilitar las funciones del lenguaje Java 8 y Jack para tu proyecto, escribe lo siguiente en tu archivo de nivel de módulo `build.gradle`:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

En realidad el `build.gradle` mostrado en la pregunta esta configurado.
Revisa la documentación: [Usar funciones del lenguaje de Java 8](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tomado de la documentación

> Android admite todas las funciones del lenguaje Java 7 y un
> subconjunto de funciones del lenguaje Java 8 que varían según la
> versión de la plataforma.
>
> Para la compatibilidad con funciones del lenguaje Java 8 se requiere
> un nuevo compilador denominado Jack. Jack es compatible únicamente con
> Android Studio 2.1 y versiones posteriores. Por lo tanto, si deseas
> usar funciones del lenguaje Java 8, debes usar Android Studio 2.1 para
> compilar tu app.

https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=es-419

En resumen, puedes usar Java 8 pero dependerá de la versión de la plataforma que soportes. Para usar Lambdas en todas las plataformas te recomendaría Retrolambda (https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)

Fuera del contexto de tu pregunta, para usar un lenguaje con más features, más conciso y más elegante te recomendaría Kotlin. Este es aceptado por Google como lenguaje oficial para Android, la curva de aprendizaje es baja y es 100% interoperable con Java (https://developer.android.com/kotlin/index.html).

Saludos